# Famo.us (Angular) Add item to beginning of ScrollView list?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, famo.us

I'm using Famo.us Angular and Firebase. Everything is going smoothly, except when I add a new item to Firebase, it will only populate at the bottom of the ScrollView list, regardless of what the sorting is. I can add it, appears at the bottom, refresh, it will be at the top.

Is there a way to inject items to the beginning of a ScrollView or SequentialView in Famo.us or Famo.us-Angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding fa-index to the fa-view in fa-scroll-view works (when items are in array).

```
<fa-scroll-view>
    <fa-view ng-repeat="(itemId,item) in items" fa-index="itemId"></fa-view>
</fa-scroll-view>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well in Famo.us (vanilla) you'd have `yourViewSequence.splice(0, 0, yourView)` to do that. It'd insert yourView at index 0 (first argument) and remove 0 elements while doing that (second argument).

But I do not know about the Angular implementation.